# Extension method for INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: extension-methods, inotifypropertychanged

Why I cannot write extension method like this? While within class I can use this.PropertyChanged != null. Is it complier limitation, dotnet specification limitation or internal code implementation limitation? My developer intuition says me that is should be possible ;).

```
public static class Ext {
        public static void OnPropertyChanged(this INotifyPropertyChanged npc, string propertyName) {
            if (npc.PropertyChanged != null) {
                npc.PropertyChanged(npc, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Error The event 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Answer (score 0):

This is specification of c# language. Event properties is not possible assign to some handler. Events fields are possible.

If you dont have any special limitation for OnPropertyChanged method (debugging, logging..), i suggest defined it in standart class,  not in extension.

You may only use this:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; // THIS IS FIELD, NOT PROPERTY, BUT YOU MAY DEFINE FROM INTERFACE
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChanged,propertyName );
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set { name = Name; this.OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public static class INotifyPropertyChangedExtension {

    public static void OnPropertyChanged(this INotifyPropertyChanged notifyPropertyChanged, PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        propertyChanged?.Invoke(notifyPropertyChanged, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```